# angular.js:13236 Error: [orderBy:notarray] Expected array but received:

Tags: angularjs

This HTML invites a button click:

```
<p><button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="ResetEventStation()">
    Choose a different station</button></p>
```

Which invokes this function:

```
$scope.ResetEventStation = function() 
{
    localStorage.removeItem("stationId");
    localStorage.removeItem("stationName");
    localStorage.removeItem("isRegistrationStation");

    $scope.stationId = -1;
    $scope.stationName = '';
    $scope.isRegistrationStation = false;
}
```

I can breakpoint and one-step through the function, but when I step beyond the closing brace, I get

> angular.js:13236 Error: [orderBy:notarray] Expected array but received: {"customer_id":97,"event_id":6,"station_id":7,"station_name":"St. Pancras","customer_name":"mawg","event_title":"Event one","token":"20000097-6ee02241-7231-4f8d-9956-5cf5022de147"}
>       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/orderBy/notarray?p0=%7B%22customer_id%22%…%22%2C%22token%22%3A%2220000097-6ee02241-7231-4f8d-9956-5cf5022de147%22%7D
>           at angular.js:68
>           at angular.js:20410
>           at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14086), :4:200)
>           at regularInterceptedExpression (angular.js:15213)
>           at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16655)
>           at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:16928)
>           at HTMLButtonElement. (angular.js:24551)
>           at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3)
>           at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3)

Googling shows it to be a filter error and, sure enough, the browsers console shows this function, which I presume Angular generated for me:

```
(function($filter,ensureSafeMemberName,ensureSafeObject,ensureSafeFunction,getStringValue,ensureSafeAssignContext,ifDefined,plus,text
/*``*/) {
"use strict";
var fn=function(s,l,a,i){var v0,v1,v2,v3=l&&('ResetEventStation' in l);v2=v3?l:s;if(!(v3)){if(s){v1=s.ResetEventStation;}}else{v1=l.ResetEventStation;}ensureSafeObject(v1,text);if(v1!=null){ensureSafeFunction(v1,text);v0=ensureSafeObject(v2.ResetEventStation(),text);}else{v0=undefined;}return v0;};return fn;
})
```

​I don't really understand what is happening. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrongly, and how to fix the error?

I can see that `{"customer_id":97,"event_id":6,"station_id":7,"station_name":"St. Pancras","customer_name":"mawg","event_title":"Event one","token":"20000097-6ee02241-7231-4f8d-9956-5cf5022de147"}` is not an array, but an not sure why it is being referenced.

Comment: Somewhere in your template, you're using the orderBy filter, to sort an array. But the input passed to the filter is not actually an array, hence the error.

Comment: show that code also where you used `filter`

Comment: I see. Thanks. I found only one occurrence, `<tr ng-repeat="station in stationNames | orderBy : 'station_name'">` . This code is not manipulating `$scope.stationNames`, but I could set it an empty array - yup, that did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look for an `orderBy` filter in your code and change/remove it. Since, it is trying to sort your array but instead of array you are having that object.

There are two possible ways where you can use this filter:

- First, in HTML, using `ng-repeat="something in someArray | orderBy: some"`
- And, in your AngularJS code, with `$filter('orderBy')(...)`

Search for these and modify them to have array instead (or remove the filter) to get rid of this error!

Comment: Got it, thanks. See my comment above. I am still not sure how it is coming about, as the function does not not manipulate the data which is ordered by the filter. Fortunately, in this case, I can simply set it to an empty array, because I am restting. It might have been tricky otherwise. It's not always easy finding side-effects, so thanks to all who pointed out the problem

Comment: @Mawg glad that helped :)

Comment: The important thing is that this shows how others can approach a similar prolbem, and go about solving it.

Comment: @Mawg Yes, that's right. That's why I chose to explain it as an answer while the actual answer could easily suffice as a comment

Comment: I wanted to look at stackb0t  from your profile, but I am one of the 3/4 of the earth's population who does not FaceTweet :-)  and that seems to be only way to get to it :-(

Comment: @Mawg yeah, sadly, I am only familiar with messenger platform for now.. chrome ext. can do good but I wanted it cross platform (on my android phone too) so. Maybe you can have an account just to talk with bots? :-)